# Prove that $1-2^{-x}\geq \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} x\right)$

Tags: inequality

Prove that
$$1-2^{-x}\geq \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} x\right)$$
for $x\in[0,1]$.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: taking derivative should help i guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = 1 - 2^{-x} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sin(\frac{\pi}{4} x)$.  Note that
$f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f'(0) > 0$ while $f'(1) < 0$.

1. Show that $f'' < 0$ for 
   $0 \le x \le 0.8$, and note that $f'(0.8) < 0$ and $f(0.8) > 0$.
2. Show that $f' < 0$ for $0.8 \le x \le 0.9$.
3. Show that $f' < 0$ for $0.9 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: Did you mean to type $\sqrt{2}2\sin$?

Comment: I suppose $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ was intended.

Answer (score 1):

If $$F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} x\right)+2^{-x}$$

$F(x)>0$. 
How $F(0)=F(1)=1$, then by value mean theorem there is a $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $F'(x_0)=0$
 $$F'(x)=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{8}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} x\right)-2^{-x}\ln(2)$$
Note that $F'(0)<0$ and $F'(1)>0$, also $F'''(x)<0, \forall x\in [0,1]$ then $F'(0)$ is concave up, then there is a only $x_0$ such that $F'(x_0)=0$. Then $F(x_0)$ is a maximun or is a minimun in $[0,1]$, how $F(\frac{2}{3})<1$ then  $F(x_0)$ is a minimun, then if $x\in[0,1]$:

$$F(x)\leq1$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} x\right)+2^{-x}\leq1$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} x\right)\leq1-2^{-x}$$